# How can I decode arabic and urdu characters python

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

I'm trying to convert a string in base64 into actual readable characters but some of the text contains characters in the urdu and arabic languages such as:

```
\\xd8\\xb9\\xdb\\x81\\xd8\\xaf\\xd9\\x90 \\xd9\\x86\\xd9\\x88\r\n\\xd8\\xa2\\xd9\\x8f\\xd8\\xb1\\xd8\\xaf\\xd9\\x88 \\xd8\\xaa\\xd8\\xaf\\xd8\\xb1\\xdb\\x8c\\xd8\\xb3 \\xd9\\x85\\xdb\\x8c\\xda\\xba \\xd8\\xa8\\xdb\\x81\\xd8\\xaa\\xd8\\xb1\\xdb\\x8c \\xda\\xa9\\xdb\\x92 \\xd9\\x84\\xdb\\x8c\\xdb\\x92 \\xd8\\xa7\\xdb\\x81\\xd8\\xaf\\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x81
```

when I remove the extra backslashes and put it in the terminal I get

```
Ø¹ÛØ¯ÙÙØ¢ÙØ±Ø¯Ù ØªØ¯Ø±ÛØ³ Ù
ÛÚº Ø¨ÛØªØ±Û Ú©Û Ù
                  ÛÛ Ø§ÛØ¯Ø§Ù
```

How can I convert the above string correctly?

Edit:

I got this string from an email using the gmail API. This is the string of the email:

```
DQpIaSBNT0hBTU1BRCwNCllvdXIgd29yayDYuduB2K_ZkCDZhtmIICANCjxodHRwczovL2NsYXNzcm9vbS5nb29nbGUuY29tL2MvTWpJek5UVXhNekl5T1RFMS9hL01qTTBPRE14TURrNE9EUXcvc3VibWlzc2lvbnM-ICANCmlzIGR1ZSB0b21vcnJvdy4gV291bGQgeW91IGxpa2UgdG8gdHVybiBpdCBpbj8NCg0K2Lnbgdiv2ZAg2YbZiA0KRHVlOiBKYW4gMjQNCk9QRU4gIA0KPGh0dHBzOi8vY2xhc3Nyb29tLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYy9Nakl6TlRVeE16SXlPVEUxL2EvTWpNME9ETXhNRGs0T0RRdy9zdWJtaXNzaW9ucz4NCklmIHlvdSBkb24ndCB3YW50IHRvIHJlY2VpdmUgZW1haWxzIGZyb20gQ2xhc3Nyb29tLCB5b3UgY2FuIHVuc3Vic2NyaWJlICANCjxodHRwczovL2NsYXNzcm9vbS5nb29nbGUuY29tL3M-Lg0KDQpHb29nbGUgTExDDQoxNjAwIEFtcGhpdGhlYXRyZSBQa3d5DQpNb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3LCBDQSA5NDA0MyBVU0ENCg==
```

To decode it you run it through base64.urlsafe_b64decode. In this string there will be unicode characters like those which were listed above. How do I decode those into the urdu and arabic characters?

Comment: [My answer updated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65869575/3439404) according to your extended [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

*How can I convert the above string correctly?*

```
text = '\\xd8\\xb9\\xdb\\x81\\xd8\\xaf\\xd9\\x90 \\xd9\\x86\\xd9\\x88\r\n\\xd8\\xa2\\xd9\\x8f\\xd8\\xb1\\xd8\\xaf\\xd9\\x88 \\xd8\\xaa\\xd8\\xaf\\xd8\\xb1\\xdb\\x8c\\xd8\\xb3 \\xd9\\x85\\xdb\\x8c\\xda\\xba \\xd8\\xa8\\xdb\\x81\\xd8\\xaa\\xd8\\xb1\\xdb\\x8c \\xda\\xa9\\xdb\\x92 \\xd9\\x84\\xdb\\x8c\\xdb\\x92 \\xd8\\xa7\\xdb\\x81\\xd8\\xaf\\xd8\\xa7\\xd9\\x81'
```

The following `encode`/`decode` progression could help:

```
text.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf-8')
```

> 'عہدِ نو\r\nآُردو تدریس میں بہتری کے لیے اہداف'

**Update** *I got this string from an email using the gmail API*:

```
textb64 = 'DQpIaSBNT0hBTU1BRCwNCllvdXIgd29yayDYuduB2K_ZkCDZhtmIICANCjxodHRwczovL2NsYXNzcm9vbS5nb29nbGUuY29tL2MvTWpJek5UVXhNekl5T1RFMS9hL01qTTBPRE14TURrNE9EUXcvc3VibWlzc2lvbnM-ICANCmlzIGR1ZSB0b21vcnJvdy4gV291bGQgeW91IGxpa2UgdG8gdHVybiBpdCBpbj8NCg0K2Lnbgdiv2ZAg2YbZiA0KRHVlOiBKYW4gMjQNCk9QRU4gIA0KPGh0dHBzOi8vY2xhc3Nyb29tLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYy9Nakl6TlRVeE16SXlPVEUxL2EvTWpNME9ETXhNRGs0T0RRdy9zdWJtaXNzaW9ucz4NCklmIHlvdSBkb24ndCB3YW50IHRvIHJlY2VpdmUgZW1haWxzIGZyb20gQ2xhc3Nyb29tLCB5b3UgY2FuIHVuc3Vic2NyaWJlICANCjxodHRwczovL2NsYXNzcm9vbS5nb29nbGUuY29tL3M-Lg0KDQpHb29nbGUgTExDDQoxNjAwIEFtcGhpdGhlYXRyZSBQa3d5DQpNb3VudGFpbiBWaWV3LCBDQSA5NDA0MyBVU0ENCg=='
import base64
print(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(textb64).decode('utf-8'))
```

> Hi MOHAMMAD, Your work عہدِ نو
> https://classroom.google.com/c/MjIzNTUxMzIyOTE1/a/MjM0ODMxMDk4ODQw/submissions
> is due tomorrow. Would you like to turn it in?
> عہدِ نو Due: Jan 24 OPEN
> https://classroom.google.com/c/MjIzNTUxMzIyOTE1/a/MjM0ODMxMDk4ODQw/submissions
> If you don't want to receive emails from Classroom, you can
> unsubscribe https://classroom.google.com/s.
>
> Google LLC 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy Mountain View, CA 94043 USA